# HTML form cannot be submitted

Tags: html, forms, input

I'm currently making an Advanced Search Google clone. I'm using only HTML and CSS. When I run the code and then I type the specific input in the box, I cannot submit it. When I press enter, there's nothing happens, it doesn't refresh, load or anything it just still. Can you please help me get through this problem? I'll attach the code here. Thank you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="google-logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <form action="https://google.com/search">

        <div class="one">
            <label class="inp-label">all these words:</label>
            <div class="inp-box">
                <input class="inp" autofocus="autofocus" name="as_q" type="text">
            </div>
            <label class="inp-label-sec">type the important words: <b>tricolor rat terrier</b></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="one">
            <label class="inp-label">this exact word or phrase:</label>
            <div class="inp-box">
                <input class="inp" name="as_epq" type="text">
            </div>
            <label class="inp-label-sec">put exact words in quotes: <b>"rat terrier"</b></label>
        </div>
        
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: there is no submit button in your form

Comment: Like already mentioned, there's no button. Add one and you can listen and handle the form [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for helping me. It works! Turns out my previous code was wrong and I changed to this one and test it with the enter key on my keyboard without putting submit button to the code. Thank you so much and have a nice day!